# Authenticator Lost Association with Salesforce Marketing Cloud Account on phone update

Tags: marketing-cloud, authentication, qr-code

I recently updated my phone and lost my Salesforce Marketing Cloud account association. I contacted my administrator and she is not sure how to regenerate a QR code for me to add the account to the authenticator again.

Does anyone know I or the admin can regenerate a QR code so I can add the account to my Authenticator app? Thanks!

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_overview_mfa_manage_admin.htm&type=5